# SSRS Grouping and repeat in 3 columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I am new to SSRS report. I'm trying do make a report like the following snapshot.
I'd like to represent the grouping data in 3x3 format.
I've already making the red rectangle one, but I've tried some ways to make it shows as 3x3 in one page, but still in vain.

I was wondering if anyone can give some suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that each time, you know `3x3 columns` and `rows`, why don't you just replicate the `columns` and `tablix`?

For example, instead of `5 columns`, use `15 columns` and replicate the data columns labels to display.

And,  instead of `1 tablix`, copy the same `tablix` with `15 column` and `3 times` to cover the replicating rows. Does that make sense?