# How can I display a second grouping as a header in a SSRS Report Builder tablix?

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a list in SSRS Report Builder so that I can display items by location in a tablix. There is a second grouping that I want to have as a header in the tablix. I can get the group to work on the left side as normal but when I get rid of that column it will only show the first "section" and then all the detail rows for all sections [Visual Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD5EK.png)

I hope that make sense. I did this in a previous life but can't for the life of me remember how.

I've tried moving the value cell to a merged cell above the column headers and that when it just grabs the first value returned.

Comment: show your report design with the row groups pane visible but typically you would have details row group, then a parent group above that for the section, then a parent group above that for Store. When you add the parent group, choose to add a header (or you can just add new new row within the group afterwards). You can then delete the newly generated column if you don't need it, but choose 'column only' if prompted. The header row can be merged across all cells and have the store field assigned.

Comment: That worked but it doesn't show each unique value. Just the header of the detail row. I will keep playing with it. thanks!

Comment: **Edit** your question and add a screen shot of the report design, make sure to include the rowgroup pane that is under the main design area and select the table so that the grey row headers are visible as that will help identify what row groups each row in the report belongs to.

Comment: Also, check out this answer I wrote to a similar question back in 2017 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122555/grouping-in-ssrs/46124867#46124867