# SSRS table grouping confusion

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have been trying to make a table that has the customer's name under the headers because that's what the customer is wanting but I can't figure out the grouping to have this work. I need the Customer Name to be a merged row over all the data but I'm not sure how to get that to visualize on here plus there are multiple locations under the master customer code so I will need multiple locations to show and have the corresponding invoices under it. I've tried grouping off of customer name and creating a child group using the customer number or invoice number but it either gives me one customer and all the items or all the customers and one item. Thank you for anyone that has any idea of how this grouping should work because I cannot wrap my head around it. The add on option has also not changed any results for me.

| Run_Date | Invoice# | Item Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer Name |  |  |
| Date | Invoice | Item |

Comment: can you show your report design? Surely if you just put the customer name in the group header and merge the cells it should work fine!

Comment: Take a look at this, it's pretty simple..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122555

Comment: @AlanSchofield thank you that worked perfect, and it was really simple I was definitely over thinking it.

Comment: No problem, I'll vote to close this as a duplicate. You can vote the other answer up if you found it useful.